# Cannot use JSON_OBJECT_T.parse to load object from blob generated with json_object function in trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to build a JSON_OBJECT_T object using the parse function, to read a blob that is JSON content, from inside a PL/SQL Trigger

The trigger is on a materialized view that has one BLOB type column called DATA

I now for a fact the JSON inside the BLOB is well formed, yet the following is not working :

```
DECLARE
    jo JSON_OBJECT_T;
BEGIN
 
 jo := JSON_OBJECT_T.parse(:NEW.DATA);
```

Gives me : ORA-40834: invalid input to JSON parse/load function

However, th following will work :

```
DECLARE
    ppo JSON_OBJECT_T;
    cidata blob;
BEGIN
 
 select json_object(* absent on null returning blob) into cidata from ci where cinum='RBC-CAONTORO-CS010-RTR01-CGW';
 ppo := JSON_OBJECT_T.parse(cidata);
```

Now the difference is in the first one (that doesn't work) the :NEW.DATA is a blob, which is the result of json_object(* absent on null returning blob), stored in a materialized view.

So parsing a blob column is not working, but generating on the fly the blob value with "select into" seems to be parsing fine

What am I missing?

EDIT : Adding reproducible example

Create table

```
create table tbl_source (field1 varchar2(20), field2 varchar2(20));
```

Create primary key

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_source
ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_source_pk PRIMARY KEY (field1);
```

Insert some data

```
insert into tbl_source values ('value1','value2');
```

Create materialized view log

```
create materialized view log on maximomis.tbl_source with primary key,rowid;
```

drop materialized view mv_tbl_source;

```
Create materialized view 
create materialized view mv_tbl_source 
REFRESH FAST
ON COMMIT
as select field1,json_object(* ABSENT ON NULL returning blob) as the_data from tbl_source;
```

Create trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MV_TBL_SOURCE_T 
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON MV_TBL_SOURCE 
FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE 
   payload json_object_t;

BEGIN 
    payload := json_object_t.parse(:NEW.THE_DATA);
END; 
/
```

Update source table and commit to trigger

```
update tbl_source set field2='hola';
commit;
```

Comment: [This seems to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/vtA0BZBM), at least with a normal table rather than an MV, but not sure why that would matter. Can you provide a [mre] that shows the problem? Maybe give your full Oracle version too.

Comment: This is Oracle 19. Please check edited question for reproducible example added at the end

Comment: @AlexPoole re-read your comment did not even notice you had links to some code. The issue seems to be from a trigger perspective, when trying to use :NEW.THE_DATA (which is a BLOB) in the json_object_t.parse(), which should be able to handle blob. If I parse the  :NEW.DATA, it fails ; if I use UTL RAW package to convert BLOB into varchar on the fly, it fails. If I display the BLOB with DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE somehow, grab the result, paste it in my code and parse the string, it succeeds